# Why is stability considered a desirable trait of a sorting algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, sorting

The common argument for stability in a sorting algorithm typically involves an example where a list is sorted by two criteria. For example:

```
1,4,5,7,2,6,8,9,15,65,24,27
sort by evenness/oddness and then by value
2,4,6,8,24,1,5,7,9,15,27,65
```

The claim is that by choosing a stable sorting algorithm, you can sort this list twice--by value and then by evenness--and you will then have the list sorted as you had wanted.

I couldn't disagree more with this ideology, though. First of all, the sorting is done backwards (value, evenness, where evenness is the primary criterion), which is unintuitive. Second of all, by doing this, you are calling sort() *twice*.

Now let's take a look at some documentation. We have C's [qsort(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort) and JavaScript's [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). Both of these functions, as far as I know, implement unstable sorting algorithms...

> If two members compare as equal, their order in the sorted array is undefined.

and

> If compareFunction(a, b) returns 0, leave a and b unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different elements. **Note: the ECMAscript standard does not guarantee this behaviour, and thus not all browsers (e.g. Mozilla versions dating back to at least 2003) respect this.**

...and both accept a function as an argument. This function is what I believe is called a comparator--a function that takes two values A and B, and returns -1, 0, or 1 depending on whether A is considered respectively "less than", "equal to" or "greater than" B, based on whatever arbitrary criteria the implementer chooses.

That said, what I have found is that no matter what I throw at the respective sorting functions, whether I implement them myself, or use the one from the standard library, is that stability has absolutely no bearing on the outcome of the sort when the sorting function is used correctly.

Let's use C's `qsort` as an example. `qsort` implements quick sort, and is known to be unstable.

> If two members compare as equal, their order in the sorted array is undefined.

To clarify, this doesn't mean that the implementation is unstable *per se*. What it means is that stability is *not guaranteed*, so relying on those semantics is a very bad idea. Which is close enough.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define INT(p) \
    ( *((int *)(p)) )

#define ISEVEN(p) \
    (INT(p) % 2 == 0)

void
randomize(int *list, size_t len)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        list[i] = rand() % (len * 10);
}

void
printlist(int *list, size_t len)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        printf("%i, ", list[i]);

    putchar('\n');
}

int
by_even(void const *a, void const *b)
{
    return (ISEVEN(a) && !ISEVEN(b)) ? (-1) : (ISEVEN(b) && !ISEVEN(a));
}

int
by_value(void const *a, void const *b)
{
    return (INT(a) < INT(b)) ? (-1) : (INT(a) > INT(b));
}

int
by_even_and_value(void const *a, void const *b)
{
    return by_even(a, b) != 0 ? by_even(a, b) : by_value(a, b);
}

int
main(void)
{
    static size_t const listsz = 20;
    int list[listsz];

    srand(time(NULL));
    randomize(list, listsz);
    printlist(list, listsz);
    qsort(list, listsz, sizeof list[0], by_even_and_value);
    printlist(list, listsz);

    return 0;
}
```

And this is the output:

```
$ cc qsort.c
$ ./a.out
100, 111, 12, 122, 96, 50, 52, 96, 173, 125, 135, 173, 78, 144, 108, 60, 75, 116, 24, 180,
12, 24, 50, 52, 60, 78, 96, 96, 100, 108, 116, 122, 144, 180, 75, 111, 125, 135, 173, 173,
```

So putting all of the sorting criteria inside the comparator and sorting once gave me the sorted list I wanted. It only took me one sort, and the criteria was able to be given in-order (even first, value second).

As this renders stability ostensibly irrelevant to the outcome, why should one be concerned with the stability of a sorting algorithm?

Comment: Because not all computing problems work well under the constraint "You can only sort once!". Many data-keeping operations involve long-standing data collections that are queried time and again for *different* primary criteria.

Comment: @KilianFoth you should put that in an answer and elaborate on it

Comment: The quotes don't say that the standard implementation **is** unstable, but that the implementation **may** (i.e. is free to) use an instable algo.

Comment: @Christophe I realize that; my wording was ambiguous. Edited.

Comment: Your statement that you can put all the criteria in the comparison function makes a very strong assumption: namely that you *know* all the criteria. Imagine, you want to sort a list of students by school year. There will be many students who compare equal. The list of students is pre-sorted according to some criteria that you don't know. You would like to preserve this ordering within the age groups because there is probably some reason for why they are ordered this way.

Comment: @JörgWMittag That sounds like an extreme situation. In such a situation, is there any reason why the "mystery ordering" couldn't be expressed by storing the index value with each element and factoring that into a comparator (i.e. when the primary criteria yields 0, defer to the relative indices). Granted, you have a point, it would probably be simpler to use a stable sort.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The common argument for stability in a sorting algorithm typically involves an example where a list is sorted by two criteria. For example:
>
> ```
> 1,4,5,7,2,6,8,9,15,65,24,27
> sort by evenness/oddness and then by value
> 2,4,6,8,24,1,5,7,9,15,27,65
> ```
>
> The claim is that by choosing a stable sorting algorithm, you can sort this list twice--by value and then by evenness--and you will then have the list sorted as you had wanted.

This example seems to have seriously mislead you with regards to what "stable sort" implies.

A better example would be

> Given a numerically ordered list of numbers: `1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,15,24,27,65`
>   When you sort this list by evenness/oddness with a stable sorting algorithm, then the sub-list of even and odd numbers will still be numerically ordered: `2,4,6,8,24,1,5,7,9,15,27,65`.

A stable sorting algorithm does not imply (or require) that the `sort()` function gets called twice. Getting the input numerically ordered is not part of the stable sorting algorithm, but rather a tool to show the stability property of the sorting algorithm.

A stable sorting algorithm only states that elements that are equal according to the comparator are kept in the same relative order as in the input. This can be shown with input that is pre-sorted according to a different criterion, or with more complex data structures where not all fields contribute to the sorting, but those more complex data structures make for a more difficult presentation in an example.

In practice, a stable sorting algorithm is most useful when you need to re-order user-facing data, because most end-users expect that kind of behavior.

Comment: I think what I'm having trouble understanding is, in that scenario, and I'm thinking from the perspective of a GUI like Windows Explorer, *what* justifies using stable sort over two clicks (when the user didn't indicate that they wanted the list sorted according to criteria other than by-name and by-<the last thing the user clicked>) instead of a faster sorting algorithm that may not be stable, combined with some clever use of comparators. In both cases, the end result is the same, but from my perspective, the latter case is both more cleanly sorted on every run, and is most likely faster.

Comment: @BradenBest because "faster" is not the most important metric by which to evaluate algorithms

Comment: @BradenBest, a stable sort algorithm is not inherently slower than a non-stable algorithm. the stability of a sorting algorithm is more a characteristic of the internal workings of the algorithm than anything else.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau True. I was referring more to cases like, say, quick sort (unstable) vs merge sort (stable), which if I'm not mistaken are some of the most common low-time-complexity sorting algorithms.

Comment: @BradenBest Sorting by multiple columns using multiple clicks *works because it's a stable sort*!

Answer (score 6):

> > Second of all, by doing this, you are calling sort() twice.

I'm not sure if this is the most complete answer but sometimes it's useful to `sort` multiple times in separate passes for user-end requirements. It might seem computationally inefficient but sometimes it makes sense from the user-end perspective.

A common example is when you see GUIs that are laid out like a grid/table with columns you can click on to sort the data by a particular field, like this:

[image]

In those cases it's not necessarily so practical for the user to be required to specify the precise order of multiple columns to sort as keys and sub-keys and sub-sub-keys and so on with a single sorting pass using a comparator which compares multiple fields at once to produce the desired ordering and sub-ordering and so forth (or for the software to try to remember the previous columns clicked on to generate the appropriate comparator). There it can be a lot simpler to do a separate sorting pass with each click of a column and use a stable sort as a way to minimally disrupt the relative order of the previous sort(s) the user requested by clicking.

I tend to think of the stable sort as a "less disruptive" sort which is often a bit more expensive to compute but has the benefit of maintaining some relative sub-ordering of the original data. And sometimes it's just very practical in code at least to do that in separate passes instead of one uber sorting pass with the appropriate comparator which gives exactly the desired results in one go.

So that's one example where it might be more useful to just stable sort to give more predictable and minimally disruptive results than try to do it all in one sorting pass just by the nature of the user-end design.

Comment: Not necessarily. If the user end of sorting is simple enough that it can be input by clicking a column header, then the developer can trivially implement all of the comparators for those as their own functions, and then implement meta-comparators, which take two comparators and compose from them an entirely *new* comparator. Plus, in every GUI of that sort that I've ever used, clicking one column automatically de-selects the other, and that column's criteria is used as the primary criterion while by-name is *always* the secondary criterion. No user-end programming knowledge required.

Comment: case in point, the example you show can easily be implemented with a single sorting pass, precisely as demonstrated in the question.

Comment: That's certainly true but then I'd just kind of question the effort involved. It becomes a productivity thing at that point whether it's simple to just reach for a sorting algorithm that's stable which you can just apply with column or try to remember all the various columns that were previously clicked in some queue structure which pops from the front when it reaches the maximum number of column fields while pushing to the back only to then generate the appropriate comparator dynamically at runtime and then do this uber sort. It starts to reach a point if a stable sort is available [...]

Comment: [...] immediately at our fingertips where it might be a lot simple to just stable sort on click without having to use/generate a comparator that takes all this previous remembered states into account.

Comment: It's true that it's 'simpler', but at the same time, it *is* a programmer's ethical responsibility to implement effectively and optimize where possible. I *don't* think the productivity line is justified given the performance hit of a stable sort (and sorting multiple times), especially when the program can be optimized by simply using a single "comparator composer" function that takes the two active comparators (by-name and by-whatever the user currently selected) and using that to define the sorting criteria.

Comment: I do agree it's a balancing act and if we're talking about epic amounts of data to sort and outside like a click context, or if clicking starts to incur some noticeable user-end delay, then whatever extra code required to do the "uber sort" with an unstable algorithm might very well be justified. But I just like the stable sort for its simplicity when its performance perfectly suffices for the job.

Comment: There is also potentially a not so convoluted way to turn an unstable algorithm into a stable one if it can utilize a copy of the original data and the comparator can take into account the original indices of the elements being sorted as a sub-key. I think that should work. So I do agree with you on the fundamental point that it's probably not that big of a deal for a sorting algorithm itself to be stable in nature since we can impose stability through the comparator being used.

Comment: @BradenBest, with the "sort on column click" example, you can not prevent the multiple invocations to `sort()`. As a user, when I click the column header, I expect the data to be sorted according to that column 'immediately'. When I click the next column header 5 minutes later, then the data should be re-sorted at that time, according to what appears to be a stable sort (which can be achieved with a stable sort algorithm, or a composite comparator based on the two columns). But the data needs to be sorted twice anyway.

Comment: @DragonEnergy True. I'll also add that relying on stability semantics can potentially burn the developer. For example, if using a third party library where stability is implied or even advertised, but not not actually guaranteed across all implementations.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau True, although the multiple sorts in that case are mandated by the *user* rather than the software, so it's okay. In the "relying on stable sort semantics" case, two clicks would yield *four* calls to sort, whereas with intelligent use of comparators, it would only yield two calls. The point is for the software to not waste system resources without the user's consent.

Comment: If we get all intricate in performance, then there might even be a case where a decent optimized stable sort might outperform an unstable algorithm if the data representation of the fields are parallel, the output is something like indices (not a mutated version of the original data), and the comparator that would otherwise be required would have to inspect so many disparate fields. That's going to outer space though and benchmark contest territory. I'm just like, okay maybe it can be argued as laziness, but if the algorithm suffices and the resulting output [...]

Comment: [...] is what's correct and desirable, profiling sessions of any bottlenecks show the sorting off the radar (not even appearing as a hotspot), I'ma call it done it and ship it and collect my beer money. :-)

Comment: @DragonEnergy "there might even be a case where a decent optimized stable sort might outperform an unstable algorithm if the data representation of the fields are parallel" - This sound very interesting, you should elaborate on this in your answer.

Comment: Well, performance gets so intricate but I'm thinking hot/cold field splitting. If you want to sort data by all sorts of possible key permutations with stable ordering, then probably the most efficient data rep (although a bit unwieldy) is going to store the fields in parallel as an SoA (not AoS) and the sorting algorithm only needs to look at the relevant field being sorted at the moment to minimize the stride to get from one data field to the next. I can go crazy exploring this stuff since I work in a very performance-critical VFX field (including things like raytracing and [...]

Comment: [...] fluid dynamics). We go into outer space exploring ideas on how to optimize the sorting for this particular column-clicking context but I'd generally think it's overkill, especially when the number of sorts requested is bounded by user input (we're not sorting like every single frame being displayed). I have to question why we're spending so much energy on this one thing instead of just calling like `stable_sort(...)` and call it a day. :-D

Comment: Cheers. Well, I kind of want to avoid getting too into performance in the anwer because it kind of smells bad if we're talking about the particular column-sorting GUI context I mentioned. And there's so many ways to skin the cat and there's much more to consider than Big-O here when it comes to sorting performance. I actually brought this up just to illustrate how complex we can get with this stuff if we don't want to waste any user-end resources and consider any such waste lazy.

Comment: You know, the ethics of what you mentioned is really interesting to me. I feel like we're sort of kindred spirits here because I came from the 80s and now it pisses me off that some simple application like Skype is taking over 100 megs of DRAM just to do whatever it needs to do. So we're not so far apart that way,and combined with that old school sprite avatar, I'd like to buy you a beer and talk about this stuff. But in my experience, we're getting to a point where we can't just call it a day after writing Pac-Man in 6502, and a practical requirement comes even if you're most focused [...]

Comment: [...] on optimization that learning to not optimize the things that we don't need to do so if buying you time to optimize the things that obviously do. With the particular GUI context I mentioned, it's unlikely that we're scrolling through millions or billions of fields (since that would be impractical from a UI standpoint). So the use case for the end-user is generally not that demanding. I have a multithreaded stable sort which can sort 200 million integers in 8 milliseconds, and that's not even that fast but it's good enough for many purposes, and it's not so slow [..].

Comment: [....] as to incur a noticeable delay for the user. So we have to kind of stop and say, with "laziness", so to speak, that it's not necessarily about laziness. Sometimes it's about being able to work less on the parts that don't matter so that you can work harder, like a machine, on the parts that do. That's my update to "ethics" when it comes to performance. It's "unethical" to spend too much time on things that don't really matter to users.